# Improving / increasing the quality of line-art of SVG file (blend file included)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, freestyle, svg

My goal is to export the image as an SVG then convert it to an EPS using Inkscape.  But the SVG line-art isn't well defined and the SVG file is blank how can I improve / fix this?  I included the blend file below.

I also tried saving it as a PNG file and doing a trace bitmap within Inkscpe but I had the problem of the lines not being well defined.

PS: I'm using Blender 2.82a.  I'm also willing to try a different process if someone knows of one.

[image]

[image]

Also this is how I made it.
https://youtu.be/rTVzdthjE5Q

> **Update:1**
>   I made the changes Jachym Michal suggested in the comments and made the **Crease Angle 180**.  see attached image below.  The edge lines still aren't "sensitive / isn't what I expected" **they don't follow the edges of the image.**

[image: Screenshot of SVG image]

Comment: Hello :). You can change thickness and color of the freestyle lines in *View Layer Tab > Freestyle Line Set*.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks.  I made the changes you suggested and made the Crease Angle 180. see attached image above. The edge lines still aren't "sensitive / isn't what I expected" they don't follow the edges of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark edges manually to render them using Freestyle.
But the 'mosaic parts' still needs to be image traced outside of Blender.

- Select Edges you want drawn in Freestyle
- Go *Edge > Mark Freestyle Edge*
- enable *Edge Marks* in *Freestyle Line Set*.

[image]